# Java, easiest way to store mixed-data types in a multidimensional array?

Tags: java

Ive got a file with some String and ints I wish to store in a 2D 'array'. What is the best way of doing this? I havent done Java for a while and i've been using VBA (where you have no datatypes), so i'm a little bit rusty.

Comment: I often get tired of asking this, but what is the purpose of this? Are you reading a file and want to store each line as an element of an array, where each element is another array of individual parts of the line? Usually it is much easier to help when we know what you are eventually trying to accomplish. Perhaps an example as well...

Comment: Definitely trying to define a type is the way to go... Then defining two dimensional array is not the easiest data structure to work with. You might want to use Maps or better even some of Google Guava Collections ( MultiSet will work in your case..)

Comment: Like @javadrinker has mentioned, let us know your use case, most often than not there is a better solution.... than defining a two dimensional array .

Answer (score 8):

Make it a two dimensional array of Objects, if you must.

A better solution is to find a common interface, and make it a two dimensional array of that interface.

The best solution is to do something like

```
public class Entry {

  private String name;

  private int value;

  public Entry(String name, int value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

}
```

And make it a single dimensional array of `Entry`s.  Note that if you really wanted to "go for the gold" rename the above `Entry` class to a class name that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

If the strings and the integers are in any relation, maybe a map might help you. Example, if you have strings, that map to integers (int and Integer can be easily converted. Read up on autoboxing):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Teststring", 5);
```

This would be for a lookup list, where order is not important. If you need ordering, use for example a TreeMap.

Also you should check out [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), which is a free library that can be a huge help in handling files. (Like almost everything in Apache Commons. These libraries have saved my sanity/job/life more than once...)