# Making a mixed 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix, int

I want a 2D Matrix with one line of strings and the other line with int's. 
Is that possible?
Or do I have to save the int's as strings and later convert them to int's again?

Comment: It's sort of possible, but it's usually a very bad idea. You could create an array of Object[][] and add String and Integers to it. But don't do this. If you need to connect a String and an int, create a class that does this, and then create a single dimensional collection or array of objects of this type.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809486/java-easiest-way-to-store-mixed-data-types-in-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Make a wrapper or use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather use an object.

```
class MyEntry { 
    String foo;
    int number;
}
MyEntry[] array = new MyEntry[10];
```

But if you **absolutely must** for some unfortunate reason, you can use two types - only through an `Object` supertype.

```
Object[][] arr = new Object[2][10];

arr[0][0] = "Foo";
arr[1][0] = new Integer(50);
```

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible . There can be only a single datatype for an array object. You can make a class having both the `int` and `String` as property and use it. Never use an `Object[][]` even if there is a temptation to do so, it is an evil workaround and hacks fail more than they succeeded . If `Object` was a sound technique then they wouldn't have introduced Generics for Collection !

Comment: But it can be a type that strings and Integers inherit from.

Comment: `Integer`s inherit , `int` doesn't !

Comment: An `Object[][]` array for this is like shooting at ones own foot . Anyone suggesting to use it is wrong enough if my answer is wrong.

Comment: Integer will be functionally equivalent to int for this purpose. So the OP could use Integer objects, but regardless, that doesn't make his original suggestion a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Objects 2D array and place there Strings and Integers, but I am not sure if it is good idea to have mixed types in arrays. You should probably describe your problem more so we could figure out better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it if you do a 2D array of `Object` as in `Object[][] myArray = new Object[x][y]` where x and y are numbers.

All you would have to do is cast the Objects to their expected types before using them. Like `(String) myArray[0][3]` for example.

YOu should only do it this way if you know for certain what type the Object in a particular location will be.

However, it's generally not a good idea to do things this way. A better solution would be to define your own data structure class that has a String array and an int array as member variables. As in:

```
public class myData {
    String[] theStringArray;
    int[] theIntArray;

    public myData(String[] sArraySize, int[] iArraySize) {
        this.theStringArray = new String[sArraySize];
        this.theIntArray = new int[iArraySize);
    }

    ...
    // Additional getters / setters etc... 
    ...
}
```

Comment: No offense, but two separate arrays is even worse.

Comment: Probably you're right about that. My intent was mostly to illustrate that defining your own data structure would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the type Object and store any non-primitive Object in there.
When you retrieve them, you'll need to make sure you check their class though.

```
if(objArray[0] instanceof String) {
    // do string stuff
} else if(objArray[0] instanceof Integer) {
    // do integer stuff
}
```

etc.

I think you're better off creating a new class that can store objects of the types that you want and just retrieve them using getters and setters. It's a lot safer and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Just write :

```
// Declare and initialize a mixed 2D array
Object[][] matrix = {
    {"string1", "string2", "string3"},
    {1, 2, 3}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. If you declare as a Matrix of object then you can store string and Integer (not int), the difficulty will be after to retrieve them correctly :)